# Netlify Lambda Function does not take Params from POST Request (with fetch / axios)

Tags: javascript, post, lambda, axios, netlify

Netlify Lambda function does not take the params from my POST-request. Tried both axios & fetch.

**My Netlify lambda function:**

```
import querystring from 'querystring';

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const params = querystring.parse(event.body);
  const name = params.name || 'World'; // here I always get back 'World' - never the params.name; Logging event.body gets me {}

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: `Hello, ${name}` })
  };
};
```

I have based it on [example no. 4 here (the POST version).](https://functions-playground.netlify.com/) Since I have pretty much just copied the docs here, I suspect the problem to be in the frontend.

**Frontend with axios:**

```
axios
  .post('/.netlify/functions/hello', {
    name: 'Fred',
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**Frontend with fetch:**

```
const response = await fetch(`/.netlify/functions/hello`, {
      method: `POST`,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'Bob'
      })
    });
let body = await response.json();
console.log(body.message);
```

**Problem / Error:**

My lambda function does not seem to get the params that I'm sending to it. I do always get back a `Hello, World`, never a `Hello, Bob` or `Hello, Fred` (which would be using the parameters). What am I missing here?

Comment: Serving the functions locally with `netlify dev` you can log the POST params. Then you will see, that they are not parsed as expected: `[Object: null prototype] {'{"name":"Bob"}': '' }`

Answer (score 3):

If your POST body is JSON then you only need to use `JSON.parse()`:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    // Only allow POST
    if (event.httpMethod !== "POST") {
        return { statusCode: 405, body: "Function not found..." };
    }

    const params = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const name = params.name || "World";

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: `Hello, ${name}`
    };
};
```

[image: using CLI: netlify dev]